# Unable to catch exception in exception strategy Mule ESB

Tags: exception, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

Am getting the below error in the http connector,I need to catch the exception and perform an operation

```
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 503 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
```

Below is the code i have written inside choice exception

```
<catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)] " doc:name="ResponseValidator Exception Strategy">
```

But the catch block is not catching the exception

Answer (score 0):

check the root exception message by using #[groovy:message.getExceptionPayload().getRootException().getMessage()]
in default exception block and fetch the root exception details and use it in your choice exception strategy